# How do I get rid of this line showing for my hover effect animation?

Tags: html, css

Update: I finally figured it out. I had to add overflow:hidden to the .services-cell:hover class.

So I have this white strip effect happening when I hover over an image, but it shows a little line going across the square border as I hover over the image, even though the shape is a polygon. So basically picture a white bar going across from the top right of the polygon to the bottom left.

Here is a codepen https://codepen.io/designextras/pen/QWybXvR 
showing that little line. Even without the image showing it still shows when you hover over the shape.

I'm not sure how to get rid of that little line that shows once the bar reaches the bottom left of the image. Note it also shows the line at the top left corner as well when I hover over, so it seems like a little border line effect, but not sure what is going on.

[image]

This is the HTML and CSS to create the effect:

```css
html, body {
  background: #222;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.services-cell:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.4;
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  background: white;
  top: 50;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.services-cell:hover:before {
  transform: translate(-100px, 600%) rotate(45deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.services-cell {
  flex: 0 1 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 275px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.services-cell_img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.services-cell_text {
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1rem;
  transition: opacity 350ms;
}
 
//This is the code that causes the lines
.services-cell:hover {
opacity: 1;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transform: scale(1.2);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="services-cell">
  <img class="services-cell_img" src="https://placehold.it/250x275" alt="">
  <div class="services-cell_text">Digital Marketing</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Brian, please share also the HTML so we can see the problem in the question itself. Read about how to create a [mcve], and add one to the question. Also, complete the [tour] to learn more about the site and you will earn a new badge.

Comment: i added the html and css for the image. Let me know if you need any more info

Comment: I made the code executable, but the issue cannot be seen. Maybe there's something missing? Or is the issue in a particular browser?

Comment: I added a codepen link. Let me know if you are able to understand what's happening

Comment: I understand what you are saying, I just cannot replicate it with the code here or in CodePen, so I cannot see the problem :S

Comment: I just opened the same codepen link on safari and it doesn't show, but when I use google chrome it does. Does that mean i need to add webkit or something to my css for chrome? I'm not too familar with those

Comment: I realized what code what causing the issue and I added it to your code above. It's when it transform: scale(1.2) for some reason I don't know why that causes a line

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer. You should add it in the answer section and mark it as the picked answer once the appropriate time has passed. That way it could be helpful to other users.

Answer (score 1):

In `.services-cell:hover, .services-cell_text {`
do not scale more than `1`, so change the:

```
transform: scale(1.2);
to
transform: scale(1);
```

or if you want to keep the resize, add:

```
 overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: nah I still haven't because the animation effect I want is for it to scale bigger when I hover, so putting scale one wouldn't do anything, but transform: scale is the reason why that line is showing and I don't know how to scale it without the line showing

Comment: nevermind I just figured it out! I just needed to put overflow: hidden

Comment: I added it to my answer, I hope it will be useful for the people from the future